# What do you call this property involving a function between two complete metric spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functions, metric-spaces

I have a notion, for which I am not able to find any reference name, as I am not that familiar with these concepts. Please help me by pointing to a definition for the below scenario.

Is there a name for the following property of the setup?

There is a a continuous and onto function $e : A \to B$, $A$ and $B$ being two different complete metric spaces.

For any element $b\in B$, and for any element $a \in e^{-1}(\{b\})$,

(where $e^{-1}(\{b\})$ is the pre-image of the element $b$ in the function $e$),

For every punctured neighbourhood of $b$ denoted as $P_{\epsilon}(b)$, the pre-image $e^{-1}(P_{\epsilon}(b))$  contains a sequence $\{a_n\}$, such that $\{a_n\} \to a$

Comment: By $e(b_n)$ did you mean something like "an element of $e^{-1}(\{b_n\})$?

Comment: If the $b_n$ are elements of $B$, it does not make sense to look at $e(b_n)$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell : Sorry I messed up. Let me correct it.

Comment: @MarkS. : I have corrected.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell : I have corrected.

Comment: Looking at Stefan Böttner's answer, perhaps we would need to add to the condition that there are no isolated points an additional assumption that the function is "nowhere constant". (By which I mean that there is no non-empty open set such that the restriction to this set is constant.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : These two, I feel are consequences, and we may need not add them as conditions. IMHO need to figure out any other consequences that can be deduced.

Comment: I wonder whether (terminology) tag would be suitable here. (Now all five slots for tags are used. But AFAICT analysis tag [should be avoided](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28023/how-should-the-analysis-tag-be-used) when possible.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call the property described in question as Property P. Continuing the observations made in [Stefan Böttner's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2865353/what-do-you-call-this-property-involving-a-function-between-two-complete-metric/2871100#2871100) we get the following.

**Observation.** Let $A$ and $B$ be metric spaces and $e\colon A\to B$ be a continuous function. Then $e$ has the Property P if and only if $A$ has no isolated points and $e$ is nowhere constant. (I am not sure to which extent this is a standard therm, but it seems to ba a natural name for this. It also [appears in some books](http://books.google.com/books?q="nowhere+constant").)

By *nowhere constant* I mean that there is no non-empty open subset $U\subseteq A$ such that $e|_U$ is constant.

*Proof.* $\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ If $a$ is any point of $A$ then property P implies existence of a sequence converging to $a$, hence $a$ is not isolated.

Let $U\ne\emptyset$ and $a\in U$. Let $b=e(a)$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. The set $e^{-1}[P_\varepsilon(b)]$ contains sequence $(a_n)$ converging to $a$. Starting with some $n_0$, terms of these sequence belong to $U$ and we also have $e(a_n)\ne e(b)$. Therefore $e|_U$

$\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ Let $B(b,\varepsilon)$ be the open ball around $b$. By continuity we get that there is a $\delta$ such that $B(a,\delta)\subseteq e^{-1}[B(b,\varepsilon)]$. Let us choose $n_0$ with $1/n_0<\delta$. Then each ball $B(a,\frac1{n_0+k})$ lies inside $e^{-1}[B(b,\varepsilon)]$. And since the function $e$ is not constant on this ball, we can choose $a_k\in B(a,\frac1{n_0+k})$ such that $e(a_k)\ne e(a)$, i.e., $a_k\in e^{-1}[P_\varepsilon(b)]$.

Answer (score 3):

By continuity, the pre-image of a neighborhood of $b$ should be a neighborhood of $a$. Now if $a$ is a **discrete point** in $A$ (i.e. the set $\{a\}\subset A$ is open), that neighborhood may be trivial such that the pre-image of the *punctured* neighborhood of $b$ does not contain any other points in the vicinity of $a$. Otherwise you should be able to find such a sequence. Hence that might be the concept you are looking for.

Comment: This is not exactly what he desires. Note that continuity does not have the aforementioned property for punctured neighborhoods in $B$

Comment: An example: Suppose $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $$\forall c>0\in\mathbb{R}\quad e(c) = b_0$$$$\forall -1\leq c\leq 0\in\mathbb{R}\quad e(c)=b_1$$$$\forall -c<-1\in\mathbb{R}\quad e(c)=b_2$$ Note that if $\exists P_\epsilon(b_0)$ that contains $b_2$ but not $b_1$, OP's property doesn't hold, despite there being no discrete points in $A$.

Comment: @RushabhMehta Your function $e$ is neither continuous nor surjective (onto).

Comment: Well that's fair, I'll have to think about that

Comment: Let $U_b$ be open such that $b \in U_b \subset B$. Then $U_a=e^{-1}(U_b)$ is open and $a \in U_a \subset A$. Unless $a$ was a discrete point, you should be able to find points $a_1,a_2,\ldots \in U_a\setminus\{a\}$ such that $a_n\rightarrow a$.

Comment: You're right, this does not depend on $B$ and $e$. I would call $A$ "without isolated points".

Comment: @StefanBöttner : Can you justify : "By continuity, the pre-image of a neighborhood of b should be a neighborhood of a", from the definition of continuity of a function in a metric space. It is not quite evident from the definition of continuity in a metric space.

Comment: @StefanBöttner : According to continuity definition, $f$ is continuous at $a$ implies, given any $\epsilon$, we can always find a $\delta$ such that every point in the $\delta$ neighbourhood of $a$ is mapped to a point in the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of $b$. It Does not talk about the pre-image. So your opening statement is not justified.

Comment: I used the more general definition of continuity for topological spaces ($f: A \rightarrow B$ is continuous iff for every open set $U\subset B$, $f^{-1}(U)\subset A$ is open). A proof that this is equivalent to your definition in case of metric spaces should be given in any decent textbook.

Comment: @StefanBöttner : Ok, fine. Coming to your next statement, Suppose if the pre-image of $b$ is a set of finite non zero measure, then a substantial part of pre-image is removed, when you puncture the neighbourhood of $b$. How would you prove that a sequence can always be found? The onus of proof remains on you. If you don't make an attempt in your post, then it is considered useless, whether or not your answer is correct.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju The preimage of $\varepsilon$ ball around $b$ contains the ball $B(a,\delta)$ for every $\delta$ which is small enough. You can simply take $a_n \in B(a,1/n) \setminus \{a\}$.

Comment: @MartinSleziak : What I mean is, for example, the case where an entire $\lambda$ neighbourhood of $a$ is mapped to a same point $b$?

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks for the clarification @RajeshDachiraju.